# angular (form array) value changes is not working

Tags: javascript, angular-forms, formarray, angular-formbuilder

Form array value changes is not working. I can't console the value inside subscriber method.
Here is my basic form array code below.

```
ordersData = [
 { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
 { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
 { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
];

this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      testControl: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });

 get formGroupControl() {
    return (this.formGroup.get('testControl') as FormArray);
  }

 private addFormControl() {
    this.ordersData.forEach((o, i) => {
      (this.formGroup.get('testControl') as FormArray).controls.push(this.formBuilder.control(''));
    });
  }
```

I've called this addFormControl() function inside the ngOnInit() and if I try to see the valuechanges using this following way

```
this.formGroup.get('testControl').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('log', {value});
    });
```

this console is not working..
Walk me through the right way of handling form array

Comment: Where is the `valueChanges` snippet placed?

Comment: I don't think adding form controls will trigger a value change. It'll only happen if the values of the controls change.

Comment: valueChange is placed inside ngOninit and yes when I am trying to change the value then valueChange is not triggered. I didn't add only formControl. you can see the value is in the orderData

Comment: `orderData` is an array of objects and you're using it for adding as many form controls as its length. Later on, are you changing any of the values of the added form controls from the UI or programmatically?

Answer (score 28):

I was having the same problem (I think), forms added to the formArray through `formArray.controls.push` didn't work, I fixed by using `formArray.push` instead

Comment: you saved my day!  it makes sense now, adding to the controls array didn't actually hook the value change event together.